# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\...\node_modules\flickr-sdk\lib''

Tags: reactjs, flickr

I newly created a react app and installed flickr-sdk, then configured it and imported as following,

```
import flickrApi from "./api/flickr";
```

then I'm getting an error like this,
ERROR in ./node_modules/flickr-sdk/lib/request.js 7:12-40

Please help me out to sort this out, Thanks in advance